# Fat Framework Script for Xcode 10?

Tags: frameworks, xcode10, fat-binaries

I used this script in the post-action of the archive in my scheme to make a FAT binary framework. One that will work on the simulator and actual device.

`https://gist.github.com/gauravkeshre/eabb2a13ef6d673fadec84ca60b56b05`

Does anyone know how to convert it to work with Xcode 10?

Using the legacy build system fixes the errors, but I would rather not rely on it.

Here is the script itself:

```
exec > /tmp/${PROJECT_NAME}_archive.log 2>&1

UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

if [ "true" == ${ALREADYINVOKED:-false} ]
then
echo "RECURSION: Detected, stopping"
else
export ALREADYINVOKED="true"

# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

echo "Building for iPhoneSimulator"
xcodebuild -workspace "${WORKSPACE_PATH}" -scheme "${TARGET_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone XS' ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO ARCHS='i386 x86_64' BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" ENABLE_BITCODE=YES OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode clean build

# Step 1. Copy the framework structure (from iphoneos build) to the universal folder
echo "Copying to output folder"
cp -R "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}${INSTALL_PATH}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

# Step 2. Copy Swift modules from iphonesimulator build (if it exists) to the copied framework directory
SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Modules/${TARGET_NAME}.swiftmodule/."
if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" ]; then
cp -R "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Modules/${TARGET_NAME}.swiftmodule"
fi

# Step 3. Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory
echo "Combining executables"
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${EXECUTABLE_PATH}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${EXECUTABLE_PATH}" "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}${INSTALL_PATH}/${EXECUTABLE_PATH}"

# Step 4. Create universal binaries for embedded frameworks
for SUB_FRAMEWORK in $( ls "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Frameworks" ); do
BINARY_NAME="${SUB_FRAMEWORK%.*}"
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Frameworks/${SUB_FRAMEWORK}/${BINARY_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${SUB_FRAMEWORK}/${BINARY_NAME}" "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}${INSTALL_PATH}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Frameworks/${SUB_FRAMEWORK}/${BINARY_NAME}"
done

# Step 5. Convenience step to copy the framework to the project's directory
echo "Copying to project dir"
yes | cp -Rf "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}" "${PROJECT_DIR}"

open "${PROJECT_DIR}"

fi
```

The errors in the output log after ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **:

```
Copying to output folder
cp: /Users/aaronbratcher/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOS-Messaging-SDK-dnynwhbesxdjhmedgaxbdcjgaksx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ContactAtOnceMessaging/BuildProductsPath/Release-universal/ContactAtOnceMessaging.framework/Modules/ContactAtOnceMessaging.swiftmodule: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/aaronbratcher/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOS-Messaging-SDK-dnynwhbesxdjhmedgaxbdcjgaksx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ContactAtOnceMessaging/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphonesimulator/ContactAtOnceMessaging.framework/Modules/ContactAtOnceMessaging.swiftmodule/.: unable to copy extended attributes to /Users/aaronbratcher/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOS-Messaging-SDK-dnynwhbesxdjhmedgaxbdcjgaksx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ContactAtOnceMessaging/BuildProductsPath/Release-universal/ContactAtOnceMessaging.framework/Modules/ContactAtOnceMessaging.swiftmodule: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/aaronbratcher/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOS-Messaging-SDK-dnynwhbesxdjhmedgaxbdcjgaksx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ContactAtOnceMessaging/BuildProductsPath/Release-universal/ContactAtOnceMessaging.framework/Modules/ContactAtOnceMessaging.swiftmodule/i386.swiftmodule: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/aaronbratcher/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOS-Messaging-SDK-dnynwhbesxdjhmedgaxbdcjgaksx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ContactAtOnceMessaging/BuildProductsPath/Release-universal/ContactAtOnceMessaging.framework/Modules/ContactAtOnceMessaging.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftdoc: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/aaronbratcher/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOS-Messaging-SDK-dnynwhbesxdjhmedgaxbdcjgaksx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ContactAtOnceMessaging/BuildProductsPath/Release-universal/ContactAtOnceMessaging.framework/Modules/ContactAtOnceMessaging.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/aaronbratcher/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOS-Messaging-SDK-dnynwhbesxdjhmedgaxbdcjgaksx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ContactAtOnceMessaging/BuildProductsPath/Release-universal/ContactAtOnceMessaging.framework/Modules/ContactAtOnceMessaging.swiftmodule/i386.swiftdoc: No such file or directory
```

and then:

```
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode 10.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't create temporary output file: /Users/aaronbratcher/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOS-Messaging-SDK-dnynwhbesxdjhmedgaxbdcjgaksx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ContactAtOnceMessaging/BuildProductsPath/Release-universal/ContactAtOnceMessaging.framework/ContactAtOnceMessaging.lipo (No such file or directory)
ls: /Users/aaronbratcher/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOS-Messaging-SDK-dnynwhbesxdjhmedgaxbdcjgaksx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ContactAtOnceMessaging/BuildProductsPath/Release-universal/ContactAtOnceMessaging.framework/Frameworks: No such file or directory
Copying to project dir
cp: /Users/aaronbratcher/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOS-Messaging-SDK-dnynwhbesxdjhmedgaxbdcjgaksx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ContactAtOnceMessaging/BuildProductsPath/Release-universal/ContactAtOnceMessaging.framework: No such file or directory
```

The first path falters once you get inside the Release-universal folder because there is no .framework folder. Instead, the *contents* of the framework are there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need to change anything. Just set skip_install to NO in the build setting of the framework target. Also remove the .framework from ${PROJECT_DIR} before archiving.

If it still doesn't work, edit your question with what the ${PROJECT_NAME}_archive.log says went wrong.

Edit: Also try building with legacy system in xcode 10. 
File -> Workspace Settings -> Build System

Edit 2: For some reason Xcode 10 post action bash scripts behave differently for previous Xcode versions. Especially the line:

```
cp -R "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}${INSTALL_PATH}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"
```

In Xcode 10 this will copy the contents of the .framework to the ${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}, whereas in Xcode 9.3 it will copy the whole .framework to the folder.

So if you change this line to:

```
cp -R "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}${INSTALL_PATH}/" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"
```

The script will work fine in Xcode 10.

Script i used:

```
exec > /tmp/${PROJECT_NAME}_archive.log 2>&1

UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

if [ "true" == ${ALREADYINVOKED:-false} ]
then
echo "RECURSION: Detected, stopping"
else
export ALREADYINVOKED="true"

# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"
#mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework" 

echo "Building for iPhoneSimulator"
xcodebuild -workspace "${WORKSPACE_PATH}" -scheme "${TARGET_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone XS' ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO ARCHS='i386 x86_64' BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" ENABLE_BITCODE=YES OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode clean build

# Step 1. Copy the framework structure (from iphoneos build) to the universal folder
echo "Copying to output folder"
cp -R "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}${INSTALL_PATH}/" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Step 2. Copy Swift modules from iphonesimulator build (if it exists) to the copied framework directory
SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Modules/${TARGET_NAME}.swiftmodule/."
if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" ]; then
cp -R "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Modules/${TARGET_NAME}.swiftmodule"
fi

# Step 3. Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory
echo "Combining executables"
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${EXECUTABLE_PATH}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${EXECUTABLE_PATH}" "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}${INSTALL_PATH}/${EXECUTABLE_PATH}"

echo "Combining executables end"

# Step 4. Create universal binaries for embedded frameworks
for SUB_FRAMEWORK in $( ls "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Frameworks" ); do
BINARY_NAME="${SUB_FRAMEWORK%.*}"
echo "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}${INSTALL_PATH}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Frameworks/${SUB_FRAMEWORK}/${BINARY_NAME}"
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Frameworks/${SUB_FRAMEWORK}/${BINARY_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${SUB_FRAMEWORK}/${BINARY_NAME}" "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}${INSTALL_PATH}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Frameworks/${SUB_FRAMEWORK}/${BINARY_NAME}"
done

# Step 5. Convenience step to copy the framework to the project's directory
echo "Copying to project dir"
yes | cp -Rf "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}" "${PROJECT_DIR}"

open "${PROJECT_DIR}"

fi
```

Comment: I have no problems using this in Xcode 9.3. However, the same workspace loaded into Xcode 10 fails. Question updated to show errors.

Comment: thanks for the updated script. Glad we have something that works with the new build system in Xcode 10.

Comment: So glad i didn't have to debug this myself, even for the bounty. Will try it out!

Comment: Build process not getting completed. Any ideas ?

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: Running 1 of 1 custom shell script

Comment: open a terminal and do the following:  tail /tmp/${PROJECT_NAME}_archive.log

Comment: Where ${PROJECT_NAME} put the name of your project of course. Also what version of xcode?

Comment: in "Copying to output folder" there is "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH} is empty and ${INSTAL_PATH} is /Library/Framework

is this OK?

Comment: ${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH} is created during archiving. So im saying whatever is in ${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}${INSTALL_PATH}/ copy it and put it in our created directory ${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}

Comment: Just to clarify, your modified script worked for me even without setting the build system to legacy.

Comment: Saved my day, thanks a lot! Works on Xcode 10.1 even without setting the build system to legacy too.

Comment: Doesn't work in Xcode10.2. Only device architectures present on resulted framework

Comment: Try without legacy build system. I should flag it as an alternative solution.

Comment: When "Building for iPhoneSimulator", always make sure, the simulator name is available. I had the problem, that "iPhone XS" was not on my system. Did replace with "iPhone 11" and the script did run again without errors.

Comment: @seeppp protip mate.