# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 Xcode 10.3

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to run a project with objective C and with a private SDK
and I get the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DetectionSDK", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in SecondViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is weird (for me) because in the real iphone runs (and in xcode 11), but in the simulator does not

Comment: looks like you are missing including required framework into your project. `_OBJC_CLASS_$_DetectionSDK` is missing now sure which one, may be the Vision framework.

Comment: how would be "required"?? I added it in General-> Linked frameworks, or is there other way? thanks

Comment: Just clean and build now if you added. FYI: follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408531/xcode-build-failure-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64

Comment: I did what say the link, but was error :/

Comment: It's perfectly fine! Because there are lots of framework which are just build for x64 bit architecture and you are build on Simulator that is 32-bit architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your private SDK doesn't contains simulator slices.
To check this, run command `lipo -i path\to\your_private_sdk\your_private_sdk`.
Output should contains something like `i386 x86_64 armv7 arm64`

```
% lipo -i your_private_sdk 
Architectures in the fat file: your_private_sdk are: i386 x86_64 armv7 arm64
```

If it contains only `armv7 arm64` architectures, you need to create universal framework from your private SDK.

More details you can find here:
[How to create universal (fat) library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711648/fat-framework-script-for-xcode-10)

Comment: actually i get only armv7 arm64 , but i created an universal framework and still does not work

Comment: if you have only armv7 arm64, this mean that your private SDK built only for iPhone/iPad, not simulator. Seems you are have some problem in making "fat" library

Comment: @smithdev is your private sdk using Swift or ObjC only?

Comment: only Objective - C

Comment: I have the same problem with MBWaySDK for payments. It this doesn't work the app is useless

Answer (score -1):

You can try  - 
1:) delete the app from simulator , clean and build again.
2:)  try to reinstall  that private sdk  & then .clean and build.