# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 while compiling swift code

Tags: swift, salesforce

In my app I'm using Library like

`"SalesforceSDKCore", "SalesforceAnalytics", "SmartStore".`

I am using **xcode 13.3** .

**podfile**

```
pod 'FMDB', :git => 'https://github.com/forcedotcom/fmdb', :branch => '2.7.2_xcode9'

pod 'SalesforceSDKCore', :git => "https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS.git", :tag => "v5.3.0", :submodules => true

pod 'SmartStore', :git => "https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS.git", :tag => "v5.3.0", :submodules => true

pod 'SmartSync', :git => "https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS.git", :tag => "v5.3.0", :submodules => true

pod 'SalesforceAnalytics', :git => "https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS.git", :tag => "v5.3.0", :submodules => true
```

When running the code I'm getting issue like:-

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "*OBJC_CLASS*$_SFSDKLogger", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in SFSDKSmartStoreLogger.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with
> exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please help me to resolve  the issue.

Comment: There's a plenty of similar questions on SO suggesting a pile of possible causes and solutions for them (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408531/xcode-build-failure-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52398504/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64-in-xcode-10, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58794494/ld-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64-xcode-10-3). Have you ensured that there's no solution for your problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode build failure "Undefined symbols for architecture x86\_64"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408531/xcode-build-failure-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)